# UIControl: call-order when adding multiple target-action pairs to the same event?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uicontrol, target-action

If I add to a control multiple target-action pairs for the same event, will the control send the action messages to the targets in the same order that I added them?

I read the following References but couldn't find an answer.

- [`- addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a) of the [`UIControl` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Target-Action in UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44)

Comment: why you can't test this? it is so easy =)

Comment: You can always add a meta-target method that calls your targets in desired order. +1 for intersting question though.

Answer (score 0):

- I think this is not documented
- even you can discover it, it could change in future
- As you are adding targets, I suppose you prefer code over using Xibs/Storyboards, so i think is far better to add only ONE target and BY CODE call every code you wrote in action.This approach is more modular, manintenable, debuggable, and you can assign the execution ORDER You want.

You can also use only ONE Action for all events (in effect action will be a normal method..) tagging buttons AND use "switch" on tag...